# Apples to Apples comparison of Lead-Acid to Lithium Ion

Tags: batteries, motor

I must admit, I'm an electronics noob. I work in software, and I'm starting to realize that the world of electronics is more complicated than I had anticipated.

In a previous project, my brother built an electric truck using 24 deep-cycle lead-acid batteries. The batteries were similar to [this battery](https://www.batteriesplus.com/battery/golf-cart/e=z=go/875ae-ambulance-utility-vehicle/electric/na/sligc115), which has the following specs:

- 6V high capacity Deep Cycle power
- 230AH at 20 hour rate
- Weight of 24 batteries: 696kg

As some of you may have heard, Tesla just announced the [Powerwall 2](https://www.engadget.com/2016/10/28/tesla-unveils-its-solar-roof-and-powerwall-2/), which has the following specs:

- 14kWh
- Cost per kWh: $393
- Comes with an inverter (I have no idea what this is or if it's necessary)
- Weight: 110kg

The electric motor for this car conversion has a controller that maxes out at 3000 amps. Normal cruising amps is around 1000.

Including a Powerwall unit might not be practical for use in an automobile, but I'd like to get a better apples-to-apples comparison of one over the other, as it's possible that a similar type of battery might become available for use in cars.

Obviously the Powerwall unit weighs a lot less, but does it provide the same amount of power? And how does it compare in terms of energy storage capacity?

Comment: 6V * 230 Ah == 1380 Wh == 1.38 kWh.  *24 == 33 kWh. Anything more you need?

Comment: The inverter converts battery DC to house AC. You'd need a different system - a speed controller.

Comment: *as it's possible that a similar type of battery might become available for use in cars* Uhm, I'm quite sure the Teslas I see driving around here and there do not use Lead-Acid batteries, they use Lithium based batteries.

Comment: @Janka Thank you! That's the conversion I was missing. Curious, I had assumed that the Powerwall would have more storage capacity than 24 oldschool lead-acid batteries

Comment: @pjc50 Interesting, that's good to know. It looks like these inverters cost ~$1000. Is that normal? Is that what a speed controller would cost?

Comment: @FakeMoustache haha I certainly believe that's the case, but they don't make those batteries available for consumers. I certainly don't intend to buy a $100k Tesla just to strip out the batteries ;)

Comment: you could have just asked me ;) a couple corrections: 20 batteries making a 120V circuit. And a 200 amp fuse -- which is a lot, especially at 120V. Power = Amps * Volts^2. More info here: http://www.chetcorcos.com/projects/2008/09/01/electric-truck.html

Comment: Ha! @Chet is my brother who built the electric truck.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "inverter" is -- but theres a transformer to turn 120V into 12V to power the lights and all the regular car stuff. And then there is a motor controller that turns the 120V DC into 3-phase AC to power the motor.

Comment: @samcorcos: the customers Elon Musk wants to win are those who think they can buy the future **today** with the pityful little money they have. It's all about creating the illusion of being rich enough to buy space-age technology. At the same time, the same people espect things to *just work*, so Musk **cannot** use anything technologically advanced. Because that stuff still needs a team of engineers nearby to have it run. You cannot be at the top of the world with a consumer product. That's a contradiction in itself.

Comment: @Janka you make me sad :(

Comment: I think that's the purpose of engineers. Keep the focus on stupid reality. If you want to be happy, watch a science fiction movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 1-3kW ac inverter and it will last 20 hrs at a 3kW flat load.

230Ah*6 = 1380 Wh/bat *24 =   33 kWh

or 33 kWh / 696 kg = **48 Wh/kg**  vs **127 Wh/kg for Powerwall**

- $110 * 24 = $2640 .../33kWh = $80/kWh DC only  for your Lead Acid
- **vs  $393/kWh for Powerwall2 which includes DC-DC and DC-AC**
- a 3kW inverter might be around $800 + extra features

  - ** The inverter gives AC power out so you can use during AC power rates during the day.**
- thus your cost /kWh increases ~40%

So yours appears cheaper but more bulky and thus longer more expensive cables and consumes more storage space and weight > 700 kg

- meanwhile nuclear product costs are around $0.03/ kWh and hydro power is the cheapest

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thank you.

The weight is the biggest problem. If the batteries weren't so heavy, the electric truck could likely go twice as fast and three times as long. Not sure if there are any other reasonable alternatives... Sounds like lithium ion is quite dangerous to drive around with without encasing it in titanium or some such metal.

Comment: Tesla modules are pretty rigid. I've seen the load tests.

Comment: The danger of lithium ion has little to do with the the enclosure (aside from crashes I suppose) -- the problem in general is energy density. More energy density is more volatile and more dangerous. The hard thing is how to charge them. You have to manage a chemical reaction that changes over time and can't let it get out of hand. Also, I had to refill the lead acid batteries every few months with deionized water which was a pain.

Comment: @Chet but isn't energy density the whole point? Gasoline is more energy dense and more unstable, but we still use that as a fuel.

Comment: the critical temp Tc is the key turning point for thermal runaway. somewhere after 85'C internal

Comment: @samcorcos gasoline is dangerous! a gasoline engine is controlled explosions tens of times a seconds. thats insane. im sure cars used to catch on fire -- we just have almost a century of experience building them now.

Answer (score 0):

The powerwall is an adaptation of Tesla's car battery systems for domestic use. The car power pack can be seen here: https://electrek.co/2016/02/03/tesla-battery-tear-down-85-kwh/

544kg; 85kWh; maximum power output 350kW. Obviously beats the lead-acid batteries by a long way, but requires more careful handling. Has to be kept cool and could potentially cause a nasty, unextinguishable fire if punctured. That's why it's kept in a titanium box. The use of lots of individual cells rather than one huge cell helps with cooling and safety.

Comment: Yikes, that's good to know! Maybe I shouldn't mess around with lithium ion then!